# Ошибка в написании алгоритма лексикографической сортировки для списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, сортировка

**Задача:**

Натуральные числа от 1 до N упорядочены лексикографически. Например, для N=25 результат этого упорядочения будет таким: 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Требуется написать программу, которая определит, на каком месте оказалось число K.

**Входные данные**

Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит два натуральных числа N и K, записанных через пробел (1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 10**4).

**Выходные данные**

Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать одно натуральное число – номер места, на котором оказалось число K.

Например:

Вход: `25 17`

Выход: `9`

Причина: элемент `17` в списке

`[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

находился под номером `9`

**Мой код:**

```
def lexicographic_sort(arr: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    mid = arr[len(arr) // 2]
    l = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) < str(mid) and num != len(arr) // 2]
    r = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) > str(mid) and num != len(arr) // 2]
    return lexicographic_sort(l) + [mid] + lexicographic_sort(r)


n, k = map(int, input().split())
include_list = list(range(1, n + 1))
arr_lexicographic = lexicographic_sort(include_list)
print(arr_lexicographic.index(k) + 1)
```

**Проблема**

Один из тестов на сайте не проходит. Где ошибка и как её исправить, чтобы программа работала корректно? Конечно, проще сделать код так и он пройдёт тесты (проверенно):

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
include_list = list(range(1, n + 1))
include_list.sort(key=lambda x: str(x))
print(include_list.index(k) + 1)
```

Меня интересует, где в *моей* сортировке ошибка.

Сайт, на котором я тестирую: https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=12&id_topic=8&id_problem=38

Comment: на каком сайте тестируете?

Comment: https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=12&id_topic=8&id_problem=38

Comment: в сортировке нет ошибки. вы это можете увидеть вот так: `assert lexicographic_sort(include_list) == sorted(include_list, key=lambda x: str(x))`

Comment: Ошибки нет, есть особенность: если взять массив у которого в середине максимумы и минимумы, то будет деградация до *n^2* и стек станет *n*. Спасибо за задачу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм вы написали правильный. Но у быстрой сортировки есть неприятная особенность, с которой вы и познакомились.

*n = 1999* переполняет стек:

> ```
> $ echo 1999 1 | python lex_sort.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 12, in <module>
>     arr_lexicographic = lexicographic_sort(include_list)
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 7, in lexicographic_sort
>     return lexicographic_sort(l) + [mid] + lexicographic_sort(r)
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 7, in lexicographic_sort
>     return lexicographic_sort(l) + [mid] + lexicographic_sort(r)
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 7, in lexicographic_sort
>     return lexicographic_sort(l) + [mid] + lexicographic_sort(r)
>   [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 5, in lexicographic_sort
>     l = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) < str(mid) and num != len(arr) // 2]
>   File "lex_sort.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
>     l = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) < str(mid) and num != len(arr) // 2]
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
> ```

При первом разбиении `mid = 1000`. Такое разбиение очень неравновесное. Налево уходят только три числа 1, 10, 100, направо все остальные.

Распечатка лога `print(len(l), mid, len(r))`:

> ```
> len(l)     mid  len(r)
>
>      3    1000    1995
>      1      10       1
>      1    1002    1993
>      0    1003    1992
>      0    1004    1991
>   1990     999       0
>      0    1005    1989
>   1988     998       0
>      0    1006    1987
>   1986     997       0
>      0    1007    1985
>   1984     996       0
>      0    1008    1983
>   1982     995       0
>      0    1009    1981
>   1980     994       0
>      1    1010    1978
>      0    1011    1977
>   1976     993       0
>      0    1012    1975
> ...
> ```

В середине массива скопились минимальные и максимальные элементы - 999 и ниже очень велики, 1000 и выше очень малы. Почти всегда при разбиении одна половина остаётся пустой. Глубина стека быстрой сортировки становится линейной. Ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю почему, но если брать не элемент по середине, а случайный то все тесты проходит:

```
import random


def lexicographic_sort(arr: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    index = random.randrange(len(arr))
    mid = arr[index]
    l = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) < str(mid) and num != index]
    r = [i for num, i in enumerate(arr) if str(i) > str(mid) and num != index]
    return lexicographic_sort(l) + [mid] + lexicographic_sort(r)


n, k = map(int, input().split())
include_list = list(range(1, n + 1))
arr_lexicographic = lexicographic_sort(include_list)
print(arr_lexicographic.index(k) + 1)
```

Либо же можно брать всегда первый элемент, так тоже прошёл

Comment: `and num != index` не нужен.